# How to close MySQL connection & quit program immediately in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, database-connection

Here's my program.

```
require "mysql"

db  =   Mysql.new("127.0.0.1", "root", "some password", "test")
db.close
db  =   nil
```

When I run this program, it doesn't finishes. I need to send `Ctrl+C` to stop execution.

How can I make this program close the connection and quit immediately and gracefully? (Ruby 2.0.0)

### Update

I discovered new symptom. It hangs instead of quit and seems like running an infinite loop. Because my CPU monitor told me it is using 100% of one core. I am not still sure this is Ruby issue or MySQL library issue or my configuration issue...

Comment: At the end, `exit 0` ?

Comment: @Cthulhu It doesn't work too :( Anyway now it looks like a problem specific to my environment.

Answer (score 1):

**Your script is fine.**

In your specific case, it doesn't quit because the client times out when conecting to the server at the given IP 10.211.55.10. It never even gets to `db.close`.

I've reproduced this locally. I changed the code to connect to my local MySQL and the script quits immediately.

I can reproduce the same hanging when I manually connect with the client:

```
$ mysql -u root -p -h 10.211.55.10
Enter password: [masked]
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.211.55.10' (60)
```

The error message appears after timing out. Are the credentials correct? Does the server accept connections?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am sure that my problem is not that. Because I confirmed another test actually takes some table data and print it. But now it looks an issue specific only to me.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out workaround.
I have installed all brew, rvm, ruby almost 10 times to figure out where the problem is.
It was because of bad MySQL connector C library.

I installed the connector with Homebrew,

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
```

and used wrapper version of ruby gem.

```
gem install mysql
```

Anyway I tried pure-ruby based version and it doesn't hang. works well.

```
brew remove mysql-connector-c
gem uninstall mysql
gem cleanup all

gem install ruby-mysql

# Now everything working well without hanging at last.
```

Anyway, `mysql-connector-c` package and `mysql` gem works fine on Ubuntu Linux. (I am using OS X)
So the core problem was OS X version of C connector installed by `brew`.

This could be a little bit slower, but it doesn't matter on dev machine, because final distribution will  be based on Linux.